# Access 2010 VBA to Sort a Report with existing grouping

Tags: vba

I have a Access 2010 report with two groups I set up in design. The first group has person data (name, dob, current address, customer points, date customer last placed a order). The second group has for the current person, all of their orders. The form that calls this report has a sort by option. They can sort by the name ascending or decending, the last date they ordered something asc/desc, and how many customer points they have asc/desc. All of these sort options should work on the data in the first/primary report group. Is there any way to call this report and set the orderby in VBA when the report already contains groups? I am passing in args from the form and trying on the load
Me.OrderBy = ArgIn(2)

Me.OrderByOn = True

I have also tried this in the open event. The report opens but ignores the sorting/order by.

Thanks

Comment: [`GroupLevel.GroupOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196466.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes you can go rather than passing arguments:

1. Create 3 exact same reports but with different sorting (within report design on group, you can sort the underlying items) and have a form trigger button with a drop down or list menu for user to select specific report ordering and then call the particular report.
2. In VBA, create a dynamic, user-defined querydef (Set qrydef = db.CreateQueryDef("[QUERY NAME]", strSQL) that is called by a form trigger button on a particular SQL statement out of three for each ORDER BY type (last name, date, points). Set the querydef to the report's recordsource.

Comment: ORDER BY is ignored by Access Reports and multiple reports triples overhead of maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The best dynamic way to do this is to use .SortOrder and .ControlSource:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Set SortOrder property to Ascending order (SortOrder = False)
    Me.GroupLevel(0).SortOrder = blSortOrder
    Me.GroupLevel(0).ControlSource = strSortBy

End Sub
```

.ControlSource is the field name of your reports table/query to be sorted. The filter hierarchy is addressed like Me.GroupLevel(0), Me.GroupLevel(1), Me.GroupLevel(2), etc..

Pass in this data via Me.OpenArgs.

```
Me.GroupLevel(0).SortOrder = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")(0)
Me.GroupLevel(0).ControlSource = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")(1)
```

Call the report like:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal, strSortBy & "|" & blSortOrder
```

...and make sure the sorted field is unique in its table, if you use grouping. (Notice that Access turns sorting into grouping when you add a header).